# Latest Post by Date

Tags: wordpress, date

How can I achieve something similar to this:

http://anidemon.com/latest-episodes/

Latest Posts are organized under header of the day. I don't about the "View" count.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virendar,

Using get_posts() should solve your problem as follows...

```
    <ul>
 <?php
 $myposts = get_posts('orderby=date&order=DESC');
 $tempdate = '';
 foreach($myposts as $post) {
  $postDate = strtotime( $post->post_date );
  if ($tempdate == '' || $postDate < $tempdate) {
    $tempdate = $postDate;
    echo '<h3>Display Date Title here</h3>';
  }
 ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
 <?php } ?>
 </ul>
```

Hope this helps!  Please note I haven't included any CSS formatting.